# Firebase Hosting does not show my website

Tags: flask, next.js, firebase-hosting

I have a Next JS & Flask app that I want to deploy to firebase. This project is a non single page app. I followed all the steps of the firebase tutorial and when I deployed it locally I got this instead my webpages:
[image]

Usually when I load my project up I see the index page from there I can navigate between routes and access the website and parts of it.

The project is in 2 main folders:

- Frontend -> All the Next JS (frontend) code is stored there.
- Backend -> All the Flask (backend) code is stored there. 
  After I did `firebase init hosting` I got this folders added to and now the files looks like this:
  [image]

This is my first time and I don't know how to proceed, I am adding here the logs from the `cmd` for more info.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to run this command `firebase emulators:start` in the root folder and in the `frontend` folder but none worked.